Why is this Electrolyzer and Hydrogen Generator combo unsustainable?
I have this small Electrolyzer + Hydrogen Generator setup in my base:



The Electrolyzer says it generates 112 g/s of Hydrogen, while the Hydrogen Generator states it needs 100g/s of Hydrogen to function and produce 800W of power.
The Hydrolyzer also generates 888g/s of Oxygen, which amounts to 1000g/s of total gas. The Pumps can pump 500g/s of gases each and the Gas Filter is able to handle the full 1000g/s on its own.
Power-wise it is a closed system, and the pumps and filter draw 720W total. So the whole system should have a positive net of 80W.
Even if this all checks out and in theory this should be auto-sustained, in practice the system can't run on his own without the dupes filling the connected battery manually at least once a day.
Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Do you have plenty of water? It might just keep running out and need to be re-primed constantly? Having a gas tank or two to buffer hydrogen would probably help considerably.

Additionally, the wiki suggests simple setups like this tend to overheat pretty quickly, which could become a problem.

@PaulZ yes, I'm tapping into a big reservoir with no flow interruption. I'm not concerned about heat at this moment, but thanks for mentioning it.

The gas filter requires 120W per packet of gas that passes through. If a packet of 1000g goes through, it requires 120W. If a packet of 4g goes through, it will still require 120W.
As the hydrogen packets that you pump out are very tiny the process of filtering wastes a lot of power, this causes this setup to not be sustainable.
You need to either save power by using a cheaper solution for filtering gases, or use one of the well-tried Self-Powering Oxygen Machine setups

Wow, thanks for the interesting pointers!
